# mysql and php - get 3 or more tables in one select?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show for my users his last activities.
For this I have 3 tables that I want to show order by date the news.

eg:

```
You sell product Y (table sell)
UserX put your product Y in favorite list (table favorite)
You have a product question (table questions)
You sell product Y (table sell again)
...
```

**So I want to get from different tables the user activities (seller) and show this alerts for him. Is it possible? any example how to do this?**

table sell:

```
id
seller
customer
product_name
data
```

table favorite:

```
product_id
seller
customer
data
```

table question:

```
product_id
seller
customer
question
answer
data
```

Comment: Sure can, it's called a JOIN.

Comment: How can we know where is users `last activity` since you don't have date column in these 3 tables?

Comment: date = data (datetime)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think he/she need UNION.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You need this output : `You sell product Y (table sell)` Which mean, we need `Users` column as well.

Comment: I have no idea, I try a join but tables are so different... I thought about create a table called "activities" and make a log there. I think it would be easier to get the values, but it is not the right way (i think)

Comment: You have 3x columns in common with each table; I can't see how you can't use a JOIN. Can't you change `id` for `product_id` in the first one?

Comment: I can change to product_id... and to get this value after select and know what to write? "if it is a sell, favorite, question".

Comment: @RubahMalam. I prefer `JOIN` because union can't work if the tables have different number of values or data's in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `You` in desired output means seller and `userX` mean customer. So, I think this could works for you :

```
select data,concat('You sell product ',product_name) as logs 
from sell 
where seller = 'userid'
union all
select data,concat(customer,' put your product ',product_id,' in favourite list') 
from favorite 
where seller = 'userid'
union all
select data,concat('You have a product question') 
from question
where seller = 'userid'
order by data desc
```

Comment: oh, it is nice! thank you!!! I will try this! I don't know about this concat! I thought about check all data to see if it is a sell and write "you sell...". really nice solution!!!